# hybris checkout add on issue

Tags: add-on, sap-commerce-cloud

1. New checkoutaddon extenssion named as "myb2ccheckout"
2. Included in localextensions.xml (hybris/config)
3. classpath : in "myb2ccheckout"
4. localextensions in "myb2ccheckout"
5. spring.xml firl we have created "Multi check out flow"
6. controller

> ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="myb2ccheckout" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="myb2cstorefront"

## Base Store

> UPDATE BaseStore;uid[unique=true];checkoutFlowGroup;hybris;myMultiFlowCheckoutGroup;
>
> exception ::
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/myb2cstorefront] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   INFO|jvm 1| main|2015/09/02 19:19:05.034 | java.lang.NullPointerException
>   INFO|jvm 1|main 2015/09/02 19:19:05.034 |at de.hybris.platform.storefront.controllers.pages.checkout.steps.AbstractCheckoutStepController.addCheckoutStepsToModel(AbstractCheckoutStepController.java:115)

Comment: which version of hybris are you working on? 
btw this sounds like a good case for debugging. I dont know a lot about the multi checkout flow, but you might be missing a configuration piece.
What does your spring bean declaration look like for this bean?

Comment: hey thanks for the response.. i got solution for this..
it is chekout group name issue..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the line number provided in the error log, it seems you have issues with the checkout group. Kindly check if the bean mapping for checkout group mentioned correctly.

Do let me know if this resolves the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps resolved my problem:

1. Check if your checkout flow group is installed:
   go to hybris backoffice->base commerce ->base store ->  -> administration ->Checkout Flow Group.
2. If above property is correctly set to your desired checkout flow group then once again install the addon:
   `ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="myb2ccheckout" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="myb2cstorefront"`
3. `ant clean all`
4. I did not need `ant initialize/update` because I already did it while installing my checkout addon first time.